# Stub authentication in controller specs - Mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am trying to follow this guide https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs but I have the following error:

`Could not find a valid mapping for #<RSpec::Mocks::Double:0x3fd34ba09afc @name=User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: inet, last_sign_in_ip: inet, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, name: string, company_id: string, phone: string, unit_id: integer, admin: boolean, invite_id: integer)>`

The helper code:

```
  def sign_in(user = double('user'))
    if user.nil?
      allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)
    else
      allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(user)
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
    end
  end
```

My test has:

```
before do
   sign_in
end
```

What I am doing of wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using in your test?

Comment: Code included on question..

Comment: Is `User` the only model you use with `devise`, or you have an `Admin` model or something similar using `devise` as well? Also, do you have `devise_for :users` in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Yes, only User model. If I use something like Fabricate.create(:user) instead a double, it works well